# How to dismiss alert popup is android using appium

Tags: java, android, ios, automation, appium

## What i am trying to do:

1. I get an alert popup , i need to dismiss that and proceed further
2. on iOS it works fine using "capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);", Dismiss the alert popup and proceed with doing other element click etc

Problem:

1. With Android its not dismissing the alert, it just ignores that line of code and progress further and error is thrown

I did try with below its still not dismissing the alert popup:
capabilities.setCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);
and 
driver.switchTo().accept().alert();

## More info:

The alert popup here is asking user permission to use location to use the app.

As of now i don't want to accept that alert,i just want to ignore in my script and proceed further.

Using Appium 1.5.3ver for windows ,trying to automate for android device app
Android OS 6.0,Samsung S5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If autoDismissAlerts is not working then you can use click method to click on "No"/"Not Now" button to ignore the pop-up in Android. You don't need to use switchTo() method. It directly clicks on the button.